# Boost 1.80 Log linker error for msvc 14.3

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to migrate my application to msvc 14.3, but it won't link to Boost 1.80's log:

```
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error    LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "unsigned __int64 & __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sources::aux::get_severity_level(void)" (?get_severity_level@aux@sources@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@YAAEA_KXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual class boost::intrusive_ptr<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_value::impl> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::sources::aux::severity_level<enum boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::trivial::severity_level>::impl::detach_from_thread(void)" (?detach_from_thread@impl@?$severity_level@W40trivial@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@@aux@sources@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@UEAA?AV?$intrusive_ptr@Uimpl@attribute_value@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@@7@XZ)    miniapp    V:\miniapp\miniapp\minilib.lib(logging.obj)    1
```

I have tried every single imaginable stack overflow solution.

My boost build command is as follow:

```
.\b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.3 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --build-type=complete stage define=BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0A00 define=_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00
```

All the libraries **must be statically linked**.
I'm grasping at straws already.

I have my preprocessors in my own project set to avoid conflicts in Boost's log  library:

```
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00
BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION=0x0A00
```

Any ideais?

Comment: Have you tried the [pre-built binaries for Visual C++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.80.0/)?

Comment: I may have missed something, but as far as I checked, those are only for shared linking.

Comment: They have static libraries also.  Unpack/install the exe and you should see them.  There will be a ton of library files, but included should be both dynamic and static versions of boost.

Comment: Just tried that. Same error.

Comment: My guess is it's a Boost bug. I changed _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0600 (Windows Vista) and it worked. Guess I'll leave it like that then.